# How to Dynamically Assign Table Name in mysql Server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, dynamic-tables

I am trying To Create Tables in mysql dynamically And  Assign them Name Using The Email Address User Provided. But Whenever I try to Assign Table Name dynamically it shows me error and i don,t know anyother way to fulfil my requirement.

**Here is The Code I Wrote**

```
String TableName = Email.getText();
try {

    String myTableName = "CREATE TABLE '" + TableName + "' "
            + "(id INTEGER not NULL, "
            + " first VARCHAR(255), "
            + " last VARCHAR(255), "
            + " age INTEGER, "
            + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";;

    Class.forName(m.RegisterationString);
    java.sql.Connection con;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(m.URL, m.UserName, m.Password);
    Statement State = con.createStatement();
    //This line has the issue
    State.executeUpdate(myTableName);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the name of table should not be between `''` it can be between :

```
String myTableName ="CREATE TABLE `" + tableName + "`"
//--------------------------------^-----------------^
```

---

**Note** for good pratice don't start the name of variable with upper letter like `State` or `TableName`, `Email`

Comment: Thank You So Much.